# ASP MVC : submit button is not working , when using AJAX.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

can you help on this please :

The  submit button is not working in simple ASP MVC page after trying to open the bootstrap modal , using AJAX.ActionLink, but when I try top open directly (without AJAX.ActionLink) it is working and then calling  the controller's action at server side : here is the code 
Main Page : index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TestQuestionsAnswers.Models.Question>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<script>
    function ShowPopup() {

        $("#divmodal").attr('data-toggle', 'modal');
        $('#divmodal').modal('show');
    }
</script>

<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    @Ajax.ActionLink("Validate Data!", "Edit1", "Question", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divresponse", OnComplete = "ShowPopup" }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-sm" })
</p>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="divmodal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Question</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <div class="container" id="divresponse">Data is here....</div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" name="btnsubmit" value="Save">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Please Note: from the code above I am using this :

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Validate Data!", "Edit1", "Question", new { id = 1 }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "divresponse", OnComplete = "ShowPopup
```

to open the modal window .

the Edit.chtml:

```
@model TestQuestionsAnswers.Models.QuestionEditView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm("Save", "Question", FormMethod.Post))
{

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info"   name="btnsubmit" value="Save" >





}
```

and the controller 's action which supposed to reach is :

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Save(string btnsubmit, TestQuestionsAnswers.Models.QuestionEditView questedit)
        {
            if (btnsubmit == "Save")
            {
                List<Answer> UpdatedAnswers=questedit.Answers;

                dbaccess.SaveEditQuestionsBy(questedit);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I dont know you have installed `unobtrusive-ajax` package or not
but if not first go to manage nudget package -> search ajax and install `Microsoft.jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` package

then give this reference in your cshtml

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
```

then put debugger in controller and check whether method is firing or not.